# How can I screenshot programs in Word 2016 on Windows 10 without the aero theme?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, screenshot

Windows 10 doesn't have the aero theme. Except it does, hidden underneath.

When you screenshot with Snipping Tool, the window looks like this:

[image]

and with Word Inset -> Screenshot -> Window select.

[image]

Can I change a setting somewhere so the Word screenshot looks like it should?

Comment: It is actually worse than this: for e.g. Explorer.exe and firefox, the title bars are black/transparent

Comment: You can use CTRL+PrintScrn to capture an active program window.